# Assigning Querystring variable with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a date variable named `start` that is passed in a query-string. Using linq I need to test on another page if another date variable named `StartDate` equals the date variable passed in the url.

I'm attempting to do something like:

```
test = client.GetEventInstances().Where(e => e.StartDate == start);
```

I can then filter by events with a `StartDate` that is equal to my `start` var sent in the url

Comment: What was wrong with your attempt, did you get an exception? Maybe `start` is a `string` and you need to use `DateTime.Parse(start)` before you compare it with `StartDate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your string date to DateTime:-

```
DateTime startDate  = DateTime.Parse(start);
test = client.GetEventInstances().Where(e => e.StartDate.Date == startDate.Date);
```

Obviously you will have to check whether date was parsed or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, only trouble is that 'test' is of type  IEnumerable so that wont work

Comment: Ohk then I misunderstood your question, I thought you wanna check if any date exist in Geteventinstances , anyways what is the error with your code?

Comment: HI the error is error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'string'

Comment: Error messge is self explanatory, you are trying to compare date with string. Do this:- 'DateTime.Parse(start)' store it in a DateTime variable and then apply your query. check my update.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, although for some reason I had to use DateTime startDate  = Convert.ToDateTime(start);

Comment: @Rifki - `Convert.ToDateTime` also internally uses `DateTime.Parse`. Anyways you can accept the answer if that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`DateTime.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DateTime startDateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParse(start, out startDateTime))
    client.GetEventInstances().Where(e => e.StartDate.Date == startDateTime.Date);
else
    /* query can't be parsed, do whatever you need to do */
```